# Partial Differential Equation of a composite function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[My textbook says that the 2nd equation is right but I don't get why there are two extra terms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4dnJ.jpg)

I think maybe the terms were added because z is a dependent variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a function of two variables, $g(x,y) := f(u(x,y,z(x,y)),v(x,y,z(x,y)))$, of which you take the partial derivative with respect to $x$. On the right-hand side there is a composition of *three* functions, which means that you need to apply the chain rule twice.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Thank You @Christoph